# The Infamous "Exceeds VM Budget" Issue

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory

So I have an APP that loops and continuously draws many png files to a canvas. In the constructor for the thread, for some of the pngs I declare Drawable and some Bitmap handles and assign them (respectively) like so:

```
 Drawablename = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pngresource);
 mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bckgrnd);
```

Keep in mind I do both methods, MANY times. (even though most of the images are fairly small)

Well... the problem i'm getting is that when trying to start this app on older devices (specifically like the original droid and older) it force closes with the VM budget error.

From research, I've noticed that this seems to be a common problem. (The app runs fine on all newer devices such as droid x, every tablet at best buy, charge, atrix, etc.)

So my question is could I be doing something better?

Is one of these methods of referencing the pngs superior? 
Also What exactly is happening here? I need to be able to reference the Image to draw at any time. In other words, at any given instant I could call Draw on one of the handles.

The fixes I've seen for similar problems involve calling the Garbage collector, but would that help me since I would need the Images later anyway? Or is this exclusively a problem with the way i'm referencing the pngs from the drawable folder?

Sorry if this is confusing, i'm a beginner.

If I called System.gc() after every reference would that help, even though the reference is still stored as a Drawable object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common fix:

1. Resize image size, for example: `createScaledBitmap()`...
2. Reduce image quality, `Config.inSampleSize` setting...
3. Remove all references to `Bitmap` objects when un-used (setting references to `NULL`, of course). If you don't do this, `System.gc()` will does nothing, remember this! and this method call does not guarantee that the memory will be freed right away.

Comment: One of the things i'm confused about is about when my references to the bitmaps are "unused." Like I said, I may at any time call any bitmap via the animation loop. But are there somehow 2 versions of the  bitmap being kept if I don't properly release the initial allocation of the bitmap? Reason I ask is that The entire Drawable folder is currently less than 1MB So i'm not understanding why this is manifesting itself as too much memory usage. More so, with the same VM budget but on newer API's (anything above 7) It works fine. So what exactly is 7- not doing that 8+ is? and Can I do it myself?

Comment: first, you always need to control your image object life-cycle; second, the physical size of the images on folder is not the same as they are loaded onto memory, which is much bigger. In newer API, the VM certainly is developed to be smarter to detect and collect garbage memory, but not perfect.

Comment: So, to be clear. Let me get this straight, correct me where i'm wrong... There Are 2 versions of the image being loaded to the memory one being stored under the handle, and the original loaded from the resources file, and API 7 and below doesn't free the original after it's assigned, while api 8 does?

Comment: You can also use [SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)

Comment: For Some reason, I changed the largest Drawable To be referenced via the Bitmap Method, and the app works!!! Since referencing the bitmaps this way is actually a good thing for other reasons in my app, I think I might eliminate the Drawable objects whenever I can. It seems to conserve memory???